# guacamole users with admin perms

Tags: apache2, vnc, tightvnc

I installed guacamole from source after a few hours of toil and trying out serveral outdated guides. But at this point I can go to the site and log into the guac web interface and connect to the guacd alright.

Though I couldn't find out what is the correct syntax to be used in the user-mapping.xml in order for me to have a root account that can have all the perms. Right now my account is only limited to joining rdps or vncs I allow within that conf.

Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, this is a whole another thing to mess with here: https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/jdbc-auth.html

So the quick way would just to be using a a script to set it up. Like guac-install.